# Leaflet broken tiles with ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, leaflet

Ionic displays these broken tiles when loading a map.

[image: View]

I've tried both loading bower and straight from Leaflet but nothing has changed. I'm using a special Leaflet Directive but event with pure leaflet code, I still get these broken tiles.

including the libraries in index.html

```
<!-- Extra libraries -->
        <script src="js/lib/leaflet/leaflet.css"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/leaflet/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
```

map.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Map">
    <ion-content scroll="false">
        <leaflet id="map" center="map.center" defaults="map.defaults"></leaflet>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controllers.js

```
var app = angular.module('controllers', ['leaflet-directive']);

app.controller('MapController', function($scope) {
    $scope.map = {
        defaults: {
            tileLayer: 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            maxZoom: 18,
            zoomControlPosition: 'bottomleft'
        },
        center: {
            lat: 51.505,
            lng: -0.09,
            zoom: 4
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!-- Extra libraries -->
<script src="js/lib/leaflet/leaflet.css"></script>
<script src="js/lib/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/leaflet/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
```

The first line. The CSS file was accidentally linked as a script instead of a stylesheet. Without leaflet.css, there was a problem drawing the map.

The new code should be:

```
<!-- Extra libraries -->
<link href="js/lib/leaflet/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/lib/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/leaflet/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

are you sure this is correct?

```
    center: {
        lat: 51.505,
        lng: -0.09,
        zoom: 4
    }
```

i have a complete working example here: [DC Web Women Code(Her) Ionic Framework Sample App](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/dcww/blob/master/www/js/controllers.js#L188)